# Плавное исчезновение объекта JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно чтобы объект, скажем div, сначала изменил свою непрозрачность на 0, а затем исчез. Думал сделать через display: none, но от лучшего способа **плавного скрытия объекта с его полным исчезновением из DOM** не откажусь. 
Спасибо.

Вот упрощенный код:

```
.block {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: red;
 }
```

- Приношу извинения за неправильно сформулированный вопрос. Я знаю, что display: none не анимируется, и задал вопрос, чтобы получить максимально эффективный  способ решения проблемы плавного и полного исчезновения объекта, в том числе сделав его невидимым для событий.

Comment: лучше не завезли

Comment: Можно реализовать при помощи `animation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свойство display не анимируется, но ты можешь порабоать со свойством visibility + opacity. Тебе это подойдет.

Если тебе заранее известнs размеры, то можно использовать ее. Если же нет. то, заменить ее на вариант анимации 2. Второй более универсальный. Свойство visibility сделает его невосприимчивым к событиям, но оставит геометрию, а позиционипрование выбьет из потока. Это если не заморачиваться.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.first {
  background-color: tomato;
  animation: fade1 1s 2s forwards;
}

.second {
  background-color: aqua;
  animation: fade2 1s 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fade2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="first">Hide me with height</div>
<div class="second">Hide me with visibility</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum dolorum voluptate laboriosam enim sed blanditiis quam adipisci, ab numquam asperiores vel? Dolorem voluptas fugit vero, ipsa ea maiores ad. Nobis!</p>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('button.one').click(()=>{
    $('.example').fadeOut(2000);
});

$('button.two').click(()=>{
    $('.example').fadeOut();
});

$('button.reset').click(()=>{
    $('.example').fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.example{
    background:grey;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

body{
    background:#232323
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example"></div>
<button class="one">click1</button>
<button class="two">click2</button>
<button class="reset">reset</button>
```